# Rails MySql:Empty result in development mode

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

i got this call in my controller:

```
@tournaments = Tournament.unignored.all(
:include => [:matches,:sport,:category],
:conditions=> ["matches.status in (0,4) 
               && matches.date < ?",
               Time.now.end_of_week + 1.day],
:order => "sports.sort ASC, categories.sort ASC, tournaments.sort ASC")
```

All works out in production mode and in the development console as well. But when I try to browse to that certain page in development mode i get:

The error occurred while evaluating `nil.each`

When I paste the created `SQL` Query into `MySQL` Browser there are results.

```
It refers to mysql2 (0.2.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:587:in `select'
```

The query arrives correctly in this one.

Did anyone had similar problems? This error came out of nowhere. No updates etc...

Thanks!

```
Rails 3.0.9 MySql 5.5 Ruby 1.8.7 and mysql2 0.2.11 gem
```

Comment: The included category messed it up. Still have no idea why it works out on the server.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use `:joins` instead of `:include`.

the `:include` option to `all` (and `find` and `where` etc) tells rails to *separately* do a query to load all the ncessary data for the given associated records.

The `:join` option gets rails to perform an SQL query that JOIN`s the associated models so you can query on their fields.

If you want to both query on the fields and preload them into the associations, you need to do both:

```
@tournaments = Tournament.unignored.all(
:include => [:matches,:sport,:category],
:joins => [:matches,:sport,:category],
:conditions=> ["matches.status in (0,4) 
               && matches.date < ?",
               Time.now.end_of_week + 1.day],
:order => "sports.sort ASC, categories.sort ASC, tournaments.sort ASC")
```